# Different between obj=nil and [obj removeFromSuperview] in iphone?

Tags: objective-c

What is the difference between removeFromSuperview and = nil for the object?
When you give = nil for object, whether it will reduce memory of the object holding?

Sri

Answer (score 7, accepted):

when you set obj=nil you are just severing the pointer to the object, the object (or view in this case), still exists in memory. if you do [obj removeFromSuperview] the retain count is decremented in the view, if it reaches zero it will be released from memory.

Comment: Hi Andres, really thanks for immediate reply, i have one more doubt. in my tabbarcontroller application i have 4 tabs, each have navigation controller, then view controller.. one view controller having nearly using 50 objects like UILabel, tableview, webview.. when i navigate the page around 1 hr and above, am getting first level of memory warning. FYI, am getting all the values from webservices. So performance all decreased when memory increased.. can you help me out how should come out from this. am expecting your answer. thanks in advance.